# Tailpipe tip color analysis [PHOTO] What is the good tailpipe tip color?

Tags: nissan, exhaust, gasoline-direct-injection

My Nissan Sylphy with a **2L Neo Direction Injection** engine was running rich due to 2 faulty injectors (leaking) and I replaced all 4 injectors three months ago.

I have put 2000Km during this three months time now.

When I was running rich, my tail pipe was rich black; even after cleaning and riding 50Km in the city, it turned in to black again.

So, I knew that the black color is due to the rich condition and now, what do you guys think about my tailpipe tip now? I'm assuming that this is the perfect color anyone should have?

[image: What is good tailpipe tip color]

PS:  I did a search before post this and found some forum discussions too. Some says that the brown color is okay and some says different stuffs. So, I wanted to clarify.

*I'm thinking that the brown color is due to my rusted tailpipe and I have grey color above that.*

Comment: Have you researched this anywhere?

Comment: @SolarMike Yes I did. I found some forum discussions too. Some says that the brown color is okay and some says different stuffs. So, I wanted to clarify. Thanks!

Comment: Then add that to your original question - then people can give informed answers.

Comment: @SolarMike already :)

Comment: The sources to those? Either as they may be helpful or to be avoided...

Comment: @SolarMike https://www.hdforums.com/forum/exhaust-system-topics/682216-brown-color-inside-of-exhaust-pipe.html, http://www.motorcycleforum.com/96-suzuki/114866-exhaust-pipe-turning-brownish-brand-new-bike.html, http://www.team-bhp.com/forum/modifications-accessories/55498-exhaust-pipe-gets-coated-brown-after-run-whats-wrong.html

Answer (score 1):

A good colour is a light grey - I spent a lot of time tuning the jets on the carbs on my v8 to get the mixture just right...

Comment: Yes. I have heard/read about that. The right color should be grey :) But, I'm thinking that the brown color is due to my rusted tailpipe and I have grey color above that. Is that right? What do you think about this color?

Answer (score -1):

To be sure, check the colour of your spark plugs they should be "greyish brown" for correct mixture.
If powdery blackish colour the mixture is too rich or conversely, whiteish colour the mixture is too lean.